# How do i fix :hover on iPhone if there is no <a> element?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, hover

How do i fix `:hover` on iPhone if there is no `<a>` element?

I'm using a `<li>` element and the iPhone doesn't open my sub-menu when i tab it.

*Example html:*

```
<ul>
  <li>Menu item (no <a> element)
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item</a><li>
    </ul>
  <li>
</ul>
```

*I answered a JavaScript way to fix this, but i want to know if there are different ways to fix this (maybe a better one)*

Comment: Hover is not a state with iPhone interfaces.  It's click or touch.

Comment: You will have to wait for heat sensitive tablets and phones to apply hover...

Comment: I know the answer, but i can't post it yet. I had to figure this out myself and couldn't find it anywhere else on internet.

But since im new here i can't post it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by using JavaScript.
The following script will add hover as class to the `<li>` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
  }
);  
</script>
```

Just add `li.hover` where you got `li:hover` in your CSS like this:

This:

```
ul li:hover ul{
    display:block;
}
```

Will be:

```
ul li:hover ul,
ul li.hover ul,{
    display:block;
}
```

**jQuery Documentation:**
http://api.jquery.com/hover/
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Answer (score 3):

Cause iPhone to respect hover states.

```
<ul>
  <li onclick="//">test</li>
  <li onclick="//">test</li>
  <li onclick="//">test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is an option, but i don't want to add an onclick to every li.
And this is also with JavaScript but my answer uses only 1 small piece of code.
But thnx for the respons, this is an good alternative (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I have found the best way to deal with div:hover to work on iphone. without using javascript

using a  `cursor: pointer` make your element to act like anchor tag

css

> ul li { cursor: pointer}

And you will also notice that when you click outside the pull down menu it doesnt close on iphone unless you click a real link. Since we can't see the cursor on mobiles this is the solution i made.

css

> body { cursor: pointer }

Comment: Wow this trick is awesome. I would change `body { cursor: pointer }` to `html.touch { cursor: pointer }` in order to avoid the pointer on non-touch devices.  Of course you'll have to add a "touch" class to the html tag after detecting a touch device.

Answer (score 0):

Although iPhones/etc don't specifically have a hover state, the hover state of links is fired when users tap them. Generally double tap will actually follow the link.

Perhaps restructure your HTML so that you do have anchors with a hover state instead of only list items. No JS required.

Comment: There is no link, I'm hovering a list-item and i want an ul inside this li displayed. And i don't want to use an anchor becouse its no anchor.

Comment: Could you post your HTML, please?

Comment: I added html example in my question

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I'd personally make them into anchors so that JS isn't needed at all, but I see you've marked the JS answer as your solution so it mustn't be an issue. My idea: `<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu item (no <a> element)</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item</a><li> [...]`

Comment: It's no issue, but i'm looking for better methods... like i described in my question

Answer (score 0):

add :focus and :active to your styles:

ul li ul{display:none}
ul li:focus ul,ul li:active ul{display:block}

Comment: Are you sure this works?  I will vote up your answer if you can point me to a working example I can test on my iPhone.  Maybe use jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.0100.tv/2010/05/fixing-the-hover-event-on-the-ipadiphoneipod/

```
//ipad and iphone fix
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    $(".menu li a").click(function(){
        //we just need to attach a click event listener to provoke iPhone/iPod/iPad's hover event
        //strange
    });
}
```

Comment: Please detail your answer, a link is not sufficient.